# SignalR triggering client hub event multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I'm using SignalR with SQLDependency to get notification whenever there is a change in one of my tables in SQL Server database. 
The notification works fine - but I see one issue. As there are more and more changes in the database, SignalR looks triggering multiple client hub events for a single change in the database.

Looking at the console, I got the following:

[16:32:30 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'sendMessage' on hub 'MessangerHub'.

[16:32:30 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'sendMessage' on hub 'MessangerHub'.
...

It looks like event is being fired multiple times.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public IEnumerable<Internal.Core.Model.ShipmentStatusInfo> GetShipments(DateTime lastStatusUpdatedDate)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Config.Instance.ShipmentConnection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var q = "SELECT dbo.Shipment.ShipmentID, dbo.Shipment.[STATUS], dbo.Shipment.[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] "+
                    " FROM dbo.Shipment WHERE name like  @name and  [Shipment].[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] > @date";


            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = lastStatusUpdatedDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Config.Instance.Name; 
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new Internal.Core.Model.ShipmentStatusInfo()
                    {
                        ShipmentId = x.GetString(0),
                        Status = x.GetString(1)
                    }).ToList();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update || e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
        {
            StatusUpdateHub.Send();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code.  Also, are you doing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507543/using-sqldepedency-onchange-event-with-signalr-adds-new-global-event-on-each-ref#comment50978082_31507543

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have included my code. I'm doing it a bit differently.

Comment: The copied log above is from your hub method or from javascript client? Is the client javasript? Also might be useful to add a breakpoint to the hub method and see when and why the invocation of the method happens.

Comment: The thing is this multiple invocation happens only after I deploy to server. It never happened in my dev environment and couldn't see it by putting breakpoint.